# PowerBook G4 vs reallity

Tags: powerpc

I have Powerbook G4 17" (OSX 10.5.8.)

It's too slow for almost everything, ima using Adobe cs3 package (it's workable for basic stuff), web browsers doesent suport that version (not even Chrome), movies are imposible to watch, cause there are no players.

Almost everything I do is either too slow or imposible, you know what I mean.

How can I improve it, or what is the best thing i can do with it, cause I don't have money for anything else.

Thanks

Comment: There were 5 different PowerBook G4 17", so which one do you actually have?  If Adobe CS3 is not a hard requirement and depending on which PowerBook G4 17" you have, then the only thing I can think of at the moment to get better performance out of the hardware with more up-to-date software,  I'd consider installing Linux on it.  Otherwise it's not much more than a paper weight (IMO).

Comment: Let's put this on hold as asking anyone for suggestions doesn't work well for focused Q/A sites. If you wanted to focus on one specific thing that's slow and ask if you can optimize that - perhaps this would be worth reopening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you can speed up an older computer in two different ways:

1. Faster HD (7200RPM for example) or an SSD
2. More RAM

Installing a different OS on it might result in a faster computer, but then you give up the reliability and ease of use and administration that come with Mac OS. Besides there is no Adobe software for Linux, only open source alternatives which have their own issues and force you to learn a new, complicated, program from scratch. But then that would be your call.

Me, I'd go with a new SSD and bringing your RAM up to 8GB (or more if possible)

Answer (score 0):

### Operating System

No matter what you do, if you stay with OS X, you're not getting past 10.5 (some macs "stuck" on 10.4 be used on 10.5 using [Leopard Assist](http://leopardassist.sourceforge.net)). While that might be fine for you, you may also find that too old and unsupported for your tastes. You're likely to find yourself wanting to switch to Linux. [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCDownloads), [Linux Mint](http://mintppc.org), and others have precompiled/optimized PowerPC versions. It's a bit of an arduous process, but it's certainly not impossible. The exact way you go about it will vary, but there are a variety of ways usually involving custom boot loaders and/or OpenFirmware.

### Applications and Software

Once you get an operating system, you'll probably need some applications. If you do remain on OS X, [there's a surprising amount of software available](http://ppcarchive.dyniform.net). Linux is a different matter, but you'll probably do a lot of your own compiling.